# OSX Terminal: Color correction

Tags: macos, terminal, byobu

[image: My Terminal]

I am running Byobu on my server and it looks good with the exception of my OS X terminal confusing the blacks. I remember seeing somewhere you can change some mode and the colors actually look right, do you know what option that is?

Comment: Looks good to me. What should it look like?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to an OSX machine, but you can try tweaking the black that's used for the status bar at the bottom.

You'll need to edit the file `~/.byobu/color`.  Try changing:

```
BACKGROUND=k
```

to

```
BACKGROUND=K
```

That's from a lower case to an upper case 'K'.